# Porque no aparecen las opciones de "método de envió" en woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

Tengo mi tienda de Woocommerce y en el chekout no aparecen las opciones de envío a pesar de que están configuradas.

Tengo instalado el plugin de Skydrop y Manuable como proveedores del envío

ya intente...

ya desinstale todo plugin relacionado o no a al tema
ya cambie también el tema del sitio y aun nada!

el problema persiste

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.